# How to Fake battery settings/status during a Flutter Integration Test?

Tags: android, flutter, adb, integration-testing, flutter-integration-test

The (Android) app we're working on is depended on it's plugged-in (AC) status.

Because we want to run the app on a real device connected to our buildserver we need a way to fake this behaviour in order to fully test the app without actually removing the device from power.

Now I've learned about `adb shell dumpsys battery ac 0|1` which allowed me to set it.
But I was unable to get this working during the test itself with:

```
Process.run('adb', [
    'shell',
    'dumpsys',
    'battery',
    'set',
    'ac',
    '1',
  ]);
```

This results in the following error:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞═════════════════
The following ProcessException was thrown running a test:
Permission denied
  Command: adb shell dumpsys battery set ac 1
```

I also tried it with `sudo`, but that resulted in the same.

Comment: Is your device rooted? I think you need this to mock battery status.

Comment: It's not rooted, but I am able to do this trough adb from my terminal. (i can successfully see the battery indicator showing the onPower icon)
But I can't get it to work from the integration test itself.